# Foursquare -- Does a script developer without a website, need Client-id Client-secret to access Venue hrs detail?

Tags: php, foursquare

I have a script written in php. I am trying to find hrs of operation of some venues through my script. I do not have a website/an app.

Do I need the client_ID and the client_Secret to use venues/hrs php APIs? If so, how can I get it without having an app/a website? If not, what do I use to connect to Foursquare? I have gone through questions here, with partial similarities. Sorry if I have missed the obvious.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Calling the API is as simple as making an HTTP request—it doesn't matter if it's in an "app" or "website," it could be as simple as running `curl` in your command line. You will need a client_id and client_secret to call the API, though. For more information see https://developer.foursquare.com/start